# [Jenkins]How can I create a shared library remotely?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

My groovy scripts are all in git repository, using jenkins checkout SCM. Some common functions are in one of the groovy scripts, I want to make this groovy a shared-library without opening jenkins and add shared library in Jenkins Manage table.

Can I add a new library using rest API or other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can load a library dynamically] from source control: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#dynamic-retrieval. This would look something like

```
library(identifier: 'pipeline-helper@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
       remote: 'https://github.com/papanito/jenkins-pipeline-helper.git',
       credentialsId: 'github.user'
]))
```

If you have a static helper class under `src/com/example/MyClass` you would do something like this:

```
def MyClass = library(identifier: 'pipeline-helper@master', retriever: modernSCM(
  [$class: 'GitSCMSource',
       remote: 'https://github.com/papanito/jenkins-pipeline-helper.git',
       credentialsId: 'github.user'
])).com.example.MyClass
```

Answer (score 0):

if your repository is align with shared library structure, like vars dir, than you can load the shared library dynamically from the jenkinsfile.

You need to use the `library` command and provide all relevant parameters.

For all parameters options you can use the snippet help option.